# What is the difference between EOS and NEM?

Tags: eosio.token

What is the difference between EOS and NEM? 
Looks like NEM can do a lot of things EOS can do. How they are different & why?

Comment: This question is little bit too wide to be answerable. What specific aspects you want to compare? See here for inspiration: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/3750/what-is-the-difference-between-eos-and-telos

Comment: Which platform is better or worse in terms of safety and security?

Comment: Your question is still very simplistic: what are you measurements for safety and security?

Comment: In terms of security, transaction speed in performance & scalability.

Comment: Ok, good! Let me see if I can find you some answers. NEM is not my area of expertise.